# Group several polylines by date in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am stuck on this for 2 days. I have coordinates that I take from a file and draw them on the map using polylines. I have checkboxes to display the dates for each route(polyline) and on hover i change the color for that route on the map. Also on check/uncheck there is a function that show/hide the polyline. I have 5 polylines. 3 of them are on 2014/10/17 and 2 on 2014/10/16.
How i can group somehow this routes by the date and when I uncheck the date 2014/10/17 the polylines on 2014/10/17 to dissapear.

Here is some code:

$this->gmaps will run 5 times. so i have 5 variables Route1,Route2 ...

```
<script>
var map;
<?
$i = 0;
foreach ($this->gmaps as $value) {
    echo 'var Route' . $i . ';';
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Here I fill an array allcoordinates with all coordinates for bounds

```
    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);


        var allcoordinates = [
<?
foreach ($this->gmaps as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
?>
        ];
```

Here I fill an array coords with the coordinates for each polyline

```
<?
$i = 0;
foreach ($this->gmaps as $value) {

echo 'var coords = [';
echo $value;
echo '];';

echo "Route" . $i . " = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: coords,
                        geodesic: true,
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                        strokeWeight: 3
                });";



$i++;
 }
 ?>
```

Set bounds

```
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();    // set bounds
    for (var i = 0; i < allcoordinates.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(allcoordinates[i]);
    }
    bounds.getCenter();
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Set polylines to map

```
<?
$i = 0;
foreach ($this->gmaps as $value) {
    echo 'Route' . $i . '.setMap(map);';
    $i++;
}
```

This is the function that gets data from the checkbox

```
function isChecked(checkbox) {
    var Route = $(checkbox).data('route');
    if ($(checkbox).is(':checked') == true) {
        window[Route].setMap(map);
    } else {
        window[Route].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

And these are the checkboxes. Here i added data-routedate because i think i must pass a second parameter to Route... or i dont know.

```
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($this->groupdates as $value) {
            echo '';
            echo '<label class="checkbox">
             <input checked type="checkbox" id="' . $i . '"  
             data-route="Route' . $i . '"
             data-routedate=' . $value['dateendRoute']. '';
            echo 'onclick="isChecked(this);"> ' . $value['dateendRoute'];
            echo '</label>';
            $i++;
?>
```

Thank you ! If i wasnt clear enough please ask.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to fill data-route with the variables for the current date like this

```
$i = 0; // id checkbox
    $id = 0; // count for each checkbox for reach route  unique var     
    if ($this->gmaps) {
        foreach ($this->coords as $index => $value) {
            $num = count($value);
            $x = 0; // counter for the end of inner loop
            echo '<label class="checkbox">
             <input checked type="checkbox" id=' . $i . '
             data-route=';
            foreach ($value as $idroute) {
                if ($num - 1 != $x) {
                    echo 'Route' . $id . ',';
                } else {
                    echo 'Route' . $id;
                }
                $x++;
                $id++;
            }
            echo '  ';
            echo "onclick='isChecked(this);'> " . $index;
            echo "</label>";
            $i++;
        }
```

And then in js to split them and create an array.

```
    function isChecked(checkbox) {
    //var Route = $(checkbox).data('route');
    var Route = $(checkbox).data('route').split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < Route.length; i++) {
        if ($(checkbox).is(':checked') == true) {
            window[Route[i]].setMap(map);
        } else {
            window[Route[i]].setMap(null);
        }
    }
}
```

In situation like this you can use data attributes as array to pass values.
Hope this will help someone.